# ASP.NET API Controller returns XMLHttpRequest cannot load URL Invalid HTTP status code 404

Tags: asp.net, angularjs

Here is the controller:

```
public class RECAPTCHAController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpPost]  
        public HttpResponseMessage Post(string response)
        {
            bool verified = Models.ReCaptcha.Verify(HttpContext.Current.Request);
            return this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new { verified = verified });      
        }
    }
```

I am using Angular to call this controller like so:

```
$http.post(API_ENDPOINT + '/RECAPTCHA/Post', { response: vm.recaptcha }).
                              success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                                  vm.captchaVerified = data.verified;
                              });
```

I am getting the following error:

```
{"Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:64189/api/RECAPTCHA/Post'.","MessageDetail":"No action was found on the controller 'RECAPTCHA' that matches the request."}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$http.post(API_ENDPOINT + '/RECAPTCHA/', vm.recaptcha).
                          success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                              vm.captchaVerified = data.verified;
                          });
```

Comment: get the following error: No action was found on the controller 'RECAPTCHA' that matches the name 'Get'.

Comment: did you changed something on the api controller?

Comment: no I did not change anything on the api controller.